# mysql inner join with takes forever to run

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I can't get this join to run. I am using easyphp, mysql 5.6.2. Windows 8 machine.

Table A = 1.5 million rows
Table B = 800 thousand rows

I believe the replace function maybe causing the issue but is there anything else I can do to optimise it further?

I have indexed, everyhting:

```
CREATE INDEX id_index ON lr_01c_compkey_v01_201411_ldpcs (urn);
CREATE INDEX pc_index ON lr_01c_compkey_v01_201411_ldpcs (postcode);
CREATE INDEX premises ON lr_01c_compkey_v01_201411_ldpcs (premises);
CREATE INDEX building ON lr_01c_compkey_v01_201411_ldpcs (building);
CREATE INDEX sub_building ON lr_01c_compkey_v01_201411_ldpcs (sub_building);
CREATE INDEX sub_build_code ON lr_01c_compkey_v01_201411_ldpcs (sub_build_code);
CREATE INDEX addi_info ON lr_01c_compkey_v01_201411_ldpcs (addi_info);

CREATE INDEX id_index ON ld_02c_compkey_v01_201411 (urn);
CREATE INDEX pc_index ON ld_02c_compkey_v01_201411 (postcode);
CREATE INDEX premises ON ld_02c_compkey_v01_201411 (premises);
CREATE INDEX building ON ld_02c_compkey_v01_201411 (building);
CREATE INDEX sub_building ON ld_02c_compkey_v01_201411 (sub_building);
CREATE INDEX sub_build_code ON ld_02c_compkey_v01_201411 (sub_build_code);
CREATE INDEX addi_info ON ld_02c_compkey_v01_201411 (addi_info);
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    lr_01c_compkey_v01_201411_ldpcs a
                    INNER JOIN ld_02c_compkey_v01_201411 c
                        ON  REPLACE(a.postcode,' ','') = REPLACE(c.postcode,' ','')
                        AND REPLACE(a.premises,' ','') = REPLACE(c.premises,' ','')

        WHERE   a.postcode <> '' AND 
                c.postcode <> '' AND

                a.premises <> '' AND 
                c.premises <> '' AND

                a.building          = '' AND
                a.sub_building      = '' AND
                a.sub_build_code    = '' AND
                a.addi_info         = '' AND

                c.building          = '' AND
                c.sub_building      = '' AND
                c.sub_build_code    = '' AND
                c.addi_info         = ''
```

Comment: that's correct. The index is rendered useless when you apply a function to the columns.

Comment: Is the replacing even necessary for the joining to work? You do the same replacement for both tables...

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg the number of spaces may not be the same on both sides.

Comment: D'oh, of course. Sorry.

Comment: Only way to fix this really is to standardise the data in some way. Either store a standard format postcode, or have another table of post codes and modify this table to just use the id of the postcode. These would both avoid the need to perform replace on the values on the join.

Comment: Thank you. All very helpful comments. I will do some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

I asume you need all those spaces in `postcode` and `premises`. (If not you just can remove them)

My advice is that you duplicate those columns (i.e `postcode_nospace` and `premises_nospace`) and fill them with the same content but without spaces. Then you will have to create a trigger to update those fields.

This solution breaks the standarizations rules and It will slow the create and update operations.

Also you can try to create a `VIEW`. Maybe it optimizes the query but I wouldn't count on that.